# React - State based document upload

Tags: reactjs, file-upload

We are trying find out options for document upload in react application.

Looking for below features -

1. Multipart file upload
2. Drag and Drop
3. Should support state / redux store

Any suggestion around package, library recommendation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used **react-dropzone** couple of times and I can recommend it.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look. Please do suggest any other option.